# Function with aliased command works with eval but not shell expansion

Tags: shell-script, zsh

Below is the function I am trying to execute. The issue seems to relate to the `main_cmd` being an alias for another command. I though this would only be an issue with sub-shells being spawned, so why would it occur with simple array expansion? IIUC that doesn't spawn a subshell.

```
my_function() {
    ... code to set opt1 based on $1 ...
    cmd=(
        main_cmd hard_coded_arg_1 hard_coded_arg_2
        -a "$opt1"
        -b hard_coded_opt
        "'$2'"
    )

    # Doesn't work.
    "$cmd[@]"
    # Works
    eval "$cmd[@]"
}
```

I would just use `eval` but that seems to be an antipattern (although I don't get why it would even matter for an expression only *I* will be executing *directly*, but that's another topic).

EDIT: Clarifying that this is using `zsh`

Answer (score 3):

Aliases are special. They're handled early in the command line processing, before parsing is fully done, and they work more like straight-up text replacement than calling a separate function.

With aliases you can do this:

```
% alias maybe=if
% maybe true; then echo yes; fi
yes
```

or

```
% alias foo='echo hi; '
% foo echo bar
hi
bar
```

or even

```
% alias xyz='echo "foo'
% xyz bar"
foo bar
```

In the second case, `foo echo bar` pretty much just gets translated into `echo hi; echo bar`, which is then parsed the usual way. With a function, that would get parsed to the command name and the two arguments, and then only a bit later would the shell need to figure out if `foo` is a function or a builtin or an external command. And in the last case, the command `xyz bar"` would have an unclosed quote if the alias wasn't there to provide one.

None of the above examples would work with a function. <sub>(Well, in as much as they can be said to "work" anyway. One might argue they more like *break* the shell syntax.)</sub>

But that also means that after `"${cmd[@]}"` is parsed and expanded, alias processing has long gone. And in fact you could do this:

```
% alias runcmd='"${cmd[@]}"'
% cmd=(printf "'%s'\n" "foo bar" abc)
% runcmd
'foo bar'
'abc'
```

which should work to show that aliases are processed before that array expansion is done.

With `eval`, it "works", since `eval` forces a whole another round of command line processing, including alias expansion. But it also involves processing any quotes in the command arguments, which you probably don't really want. See [Stéphane's answer for details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/762390/170373) on that.

Might be less confusing to use a function for `main_cmd` rather than an alias.

Comment: Ah, I completely missed that the question was about aliases and was focussing on the bogus `"'$2'"`. Not sure whether I should delete my answer or not now as it still has a few useful informations.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, nah, don't. The quotes are still an issue and it's good to point that out.

Answer (score 1):

You want either:

```
cmd=(
  main_cmd hard_coded_arg_1 hard_coded_arg_2
  -a "$opt1"
  -b hard_coded_opt
  "$2"
)
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Where we define an array that has these elements:

1. `main_cmd`
2. `hard_coded_arg_1`
3. `hard_coded_arg_2`
4. `-a`
5. `value-of-opt1-variable`
6. `-b`
7. `hard_coded_opt`
8. `value-of-second-positional-parameter`

And then `"${cmd[@]}"` (or `"$cmd[@]"` in zsh) expands to each of those arguments individually separately so we end up running the command looked up from the first element of the array (`$cmd[1]`) and with all the elements of the array as arguments.

In zsh, using just `$cmd` would also work here, but because it removes empty elements, that cannot be used for arbitrary commands.

Or (though it makes little sense to use an array then):

```
cmd=(
  'main_cmd hard_coded_arg_1 hard_coded_arg_2'
  '-a "$opt1"'
  '-b hard_coded_opt'
  '"$2"'
)
eval " ${cmd[@]}"
```

Where the array has:

1. `main_cmd hard_coded_arg_1 hard_coded_arg_2`
2. `-a "$opt1"`
3. `-b hard_coded_opt`
4. `"$2"`

And we pass them to `eval` as separate arguments (with a space prepended to the first in case it contains a `-` which `eval` could take as an option), which it concatenates with spaces in between to give:  `main_cmd hard_coded_arg_1 hard_coded_arg_2 -a "$opt1" -b hard_coded_opt "$2"` and that is then interpreted as shell code (because that's what `eval` does).

Doing:

> ```
> cmd=(
>     main_cmd hard_coded_arg_1 hard_coded_arg_2
>     -a "$opt1"
>     -b hard_coded_opt
>     "'$2'"
> )
>
> eval "$cmd[@]"
> ```

Is wrong because you get an array with elements  as:

1. `main_cmd`
2. `hard_coded_arg_1`
3. `hard_coded_arg_2`
4. `-a`
5. `value-of-opt1-variable`
6. `-b`
7. `hard_coded_opt`
8. `'value-of-second-positional-parameter'`

So you end up having `eval` interpret the:

```
main_cmd hard_coded_arg_1 hard_coded_arg_2 -a value-of-opt1-variable -b hard_coded_opt 'value-of-second-positional-parameter'
```

And if `value-of-opt1-variable` happens to be `$(reboot)` or `$2` happens to contain `'; rm -rf ~ #` you can imagine that having catastrophic consequences.

Beware that `eval " $cmd"` in zsh is short for `eval " ${cmd[*]}"` where the elements of the array are joined using the first character of `$IFS` in between. That's fine with the default value of `$IFS` which happens to start with space, but would break when used in contexts where `$IFS` has been modified (uncommon in zsh though, as zsh has proper explicit splitting and joining operators so it's rare to resort to modifying `$IFS` for that there).

If the point here is to make the command more easily to read by splitting it on several lines, the conventional approach for that and that works in virtually every shell is to use *line continuations* by inserting a backslash at the end of the line:

```
my_function() {
  main_cmd hard_coded_arg_1 hard_coded_arg_2 \
    -a "$opt1" \
    -b hard_coded_opt \
    "$2"
}
```

It's customary to indent-out the continuation of the lines to make it clearer that they are continuations and not separate lines. Some people prefer writing it:

```
my_function() {
  main_cmd hard_coded_arg_1 hard_coded_arg_2 \
    -a "$opt1"                               \
    -b hard_coded_opt                        \
    "$2"
}
```

Which makes it easier to spot when a `\` is missing.

In any case you likely don't want to use aliases here. Aliases are a bit like C pre-processor macros, which are expanded very earlier (in C in a pre-processing stage, in shell after reading and after tokenising the code and partially parsing its syntax¹), but contrary to C are only expanded when found in *command position*² and don't take arguments.

That explains why it's not expanded in `array=( alias_name ... )` as that `alias_name` is not found in command position.

Using `main_cmd() the command "$@"` instead of `alias main_cmd='the command'` doesn't have the problem as you're actually defining a real `main_cmd` command there as opposed to a token meant to be replaced with some text to be reevaluated as code under some condition.

---

<sup>¹ as after alias expansion, the syntax in the result is re-parsed which may even completely change the meaning of the command and could undergo more rounds of alias expansions.</sup>

<sup>² though see `alias -g` in `zsh` for global aliases which are expanded globally, not only in *command position*</sup>